# React: how to make a numbered list out of different components (with different layouts)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the UI of a React app I am working on:
[image: application UI]

Currently UI is made as a single giant layout.

I want to break each step to be its separate component. As you can see each component would have somewhat different layout.
Now I want to make is such that we would get numbering "Step 1:", "Step 2:" algorithmically (currently those are hardcoded strings).

I was thinking about using high-order components for this purpose, but wasn't sure if I would require them to share context or something to get the numeration correct.

Any ideas how such thing could be achieved?

Again, I will provide the layout as a separate component, step caption as a string, but the part `Step #:`  should be added during render.

Comment: Is this a documentation site for an API ? The content looks like markdown for me.

Comment: You can also try [this](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/docs/pages/material-ui/react-button.js). That file render the content of [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/) page. Basically they use a markdown [file](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/docs/data/material/components/buttons/buttons.md) with custom syntax that will transform by [babel](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/docs/packages/markdown).

Comment: UI with `code` is just one of the steps.
As you can see we have buttons, comboboxes and whatnot.

Comment: Then its just a simple application ? What's so special about it ? You can fetch your steps from an api or just keep it on a JSON file. Then loop through your step ( use the index + 1 for step title ) and use a component to render the content. You will have to define the sub components for each type of steps. Otherwise you can use the method I mentioned above. MUI documentation is pretty complex. They also have interactive things but still manages to use `md` files with custom babel plugin to dynamically create the doc pages.